# How to create packages in SaltStack

Tags: ubuntu, installation, packages, saltstack

I have installed Salt-master in my ubuntu 12.04 machine and salt minion in ubuntu 12.04. I want to install package containing like svn,mongodb,postgres,maven,python in the salt-minion. how to create package to install all these in salt minion?.Please do let me know.

when i run "sudo salt '*' state.highstate test=True"

@rome:~$ sudo salt '*' state.highstate test=True

i am getting the following error

### paris:

```
State: - no
Name:      states
Function:  None
    Result:    False
    Comment:   No Top file or external nodes data matches found
    Changes:
```

### Summary

Succeeded: 0

### Failed:    1

Total:     1

Comment: Do you mean just install these packages from the package repository? Then just add pkg: `svn, pkg.installed` (with proper newlines etc), as the docs say. I think I don't understand your specific question.

Comment: let me know where to add this line?

Comment: you have to create a top.sls and then a salt state like mypackages.sls, references by top.sls. This is plainly documented.

Comment: can you provide a package file for above and how it needs to be installed (command)?

Answer (score 0):

First create a `mypackages.sls` file with your packages

```
vim:
  pkg.installed

postgres:
  pkg.installed

examplewithexplicitname:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: mongodb
```

You need to put that in your top for selected hosts (`'*'`):

```
# cat top.sls
'*':
  - mypackages
```

Then test it:

```
salt '*' state.highstate test=True
```

Comment: what is examplewithexplicitname? do let me know

Comment: do explain this step 
You need to put that in your top for selected hosts ('*'):

# cat top.sls
'*':
  - mypackages

Comment: That was to let you know to create a state that is not named after the package your installing. Normally, `name` is inferred from the state name, but you can specify it by hand with `- name:`

Comment: kindly take note of it.
this is my result http://pastebin.com/ZGsHmfGP

Comment: With the salt docs, you should have enough information to add that to your top and apply it to your minions.

Comment: @halfgaar-this is mypackage.sls http://pastebin.com/Auk6ehb2

Comment: Not the main error, but still an error: you don't seem to have proper indentation in your config. Anyway, with the information given, plus the documentation, you should be able to figure out. Please take the time to study the documentation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12833/discussion-between-krs-and-halfgaar)